# use condition to fetch data only for admin user in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I want to fetch data only when the auth is an admin.

**The User controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    if (auth::user()->type == 'admin') {

        return User::where('type','!=','admin')->latest()->paginate(100);
    }
}
```

I got an **error**:

> Trying to get property 'type' of non-object.

Comment: How you Assign `auth` ! It should be Auth::user() , also print that and check `Object` or `Array` . If array you should use `Auth::user()['type']`

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
if (auth::user()->type == 'admin') {
```

should be.

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->type == 'admin') {
```

Explanation:

- `auth()->check()` -- makes sure there is a user logged in.
- `&&` -- stops after the first check if it is false
- `auth()->user()->type` -- gets the `type` attribute from the user

Comment: the error is gone but it didn't fetch the data! PS: it was working befor i made the condition

Comment: Verify that you are logged in when you load that route. Add `dd(auth()->check())` before the conditional

Answer (score 1):

If you are using role based authentication then You can check user role by creating the function in user model

**USER MODEL**

```
public function isAdministrator()
{
   return $this->hasRole('admin');
}
```

**USER CONTROLLER**

```
class userController
{
   public function index()
  {
      if(Auth::user()->isAdministrator())
      {
         # code...

      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Create middleware and pass route through middleware, it will work

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->type != 'admin')
    {
        return redirect('/unauthorized');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method hasRole to check whether the role is admin or not.

```
public function index()
{
    if (auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {

        return User::latest()->paginate(100);
    }
}
```